# How to setup p2p in Raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, p2p

I have to setup wpa_supplicant so that, it can perform p2p operations. But with no luck.
I have installed wpa_supplicant v2.0 but when I try to issue any p2p commands, it says UNKNOWN_COMMAND.
following are some of the outputs.

```
  root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Desktop# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
```

And output when I issue commands is:

```
  root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Desktop# wpa_cli
wpa_cli v2.0
Copyright (c) 2004-2012, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.


Selected interface 'wlan0'

Interactive mode

> p2p_find
UNKNOWN COMMAND
> p2p_stop_find
UNKNOWN COMMAND
> p2p
Ambiguous command 'p2p'; possible commands: p2p_find p2p_stop_find p2p_connect p2p_listen p2p_group_remove p2p_group_add p2p_prov_disc p2p_get_passphrase p2p_serv_disc_req p2p_serv_disc_cancel_req p2p_serv_disc_resp p2p_service_update p2p_serv_disc_external p2p_service_flush p2p_service_add p2p_service_del p2p_reject p2p_invite p2p_peers p2p_peer p2p_set p2p_flush p2p_cancel p2p_unauthorize p2p_presence_req p2p_ext_listen
>
```

Please help me configure it.

Regards

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic , try http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com rather

Answer (score 0):

You have to build wpa_supplicant with CONFIG_P2P=y in .config.
Then, p2p features are enabled if your wifi chipset supports p2p.

Regards,